# How can I filter API GET Request on multiple variables?

Tags: python, api, get, python-requests, endpoint

I am really struggling with this one. I'm new to python and I'm trying to extract data from an API.

I have managed to run the script below but I need to amend it to filter on multiple values for one column, lets say England and Scotland. Is there an equivelant to the SQL IN operator e.g. Area_Name IN ('England','Scotland').

```
from requests import get
from json import dumps


ENDPOINT = "https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data"
AREA_TYPE = "nation"
AREA_NAME = "england"

filters = [
    f"areaType={ AREA_TYPE }",
    f"areaName={ AREA_NAME }"
]

structure = {
    "date": "date",
    "name": "areaName",
    "code": "areaCode",
    "dailyCases": "newCasesByPublishDate",
}


api_params = {
    "filters": str.join(";", filters),
    "structure": dumps(structure, separators=(",", ":")),
    "latestBy": "cumCasesByPublishDate"
}


formats = [
    "json",
    "xml",
    "csv"
]


for fmt in formats:
    api_params["format"] = fmt
    response = get(ENDPOINT, params=api_params, timeout=10)
    assert response.status_code == 200, f"Failed request for {fmt}: {response.text}"
    print(f"{fmt} data:")
    print(response.content.decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the script, and dict is the easiest type to handle in this case.
Given your json data output

```
data = {"length":1,"maxPageLimit":1,"data":[{"date":"2020-09-17","name":"England","code":"E92000001","dailyCases":2788}],"pagination":{"current":"/v1/data?filters=areaType%3Dnation%3BareaName%3Dengland&structure=%7B%22date%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22areaName%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22areaCode%22%2C%22dailyCases%22%3A%22newCasesByPublishDate%22%7D&latestBy=cumCasesByPublishDate&format=json&page=1","next":null,"previous":null,"first":"/v1/data?filters=areaType%3Dnation%3BareaName%3Dengland&structure=%7B%22date%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22areaName%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22areaCode%22%2C%22dailyCases%22%3A%22newCasesByPublishDate%22%7D&latestBy=cumCasesByPublishDate&format=json&page=1","last":"/v1/data?filters=areaType%3Dnation%3BareaName%3Dengland&structure=%7B%22date%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22areaName%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22areaCode%22%2C%22dailyCases%22%3A%22newCasesByPublishDate%22%7D&latestBy=cumCasesByPublishDate&format=json&page=1"}}
```

You can try something like this:

```
countries = ['England', 'France', 'Whatever']
return [country for country in data where country['name'] in countries]
```

I presume the data list is the only interesting key in the data dict since all others do not have any meaningful values.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to be able to filter it in the request though not in the output

Comment: Unless the API allows it by using a specific body format, you can't do it at the request level